# 3 pulley and 2 masses,relation between their accelerations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

[image]

I want to find acceleration of each mass in this system. lets take length of rope between three pulleys as $L$. then we can use this relations $$L=x_1-x_0+(x_1-x_0+x_0-x_2)+x_2-x_0+x_3-x_0=2x_1+x_3-3x_0$$

$$constant=L+3x_0=2x_1+x_3$$

So i think the relation between their accelerations is $2a_2=-a_1$

but I think i did something wrong and the relation is not true because this relation is for a simple case like this

[image]

So my question is:

what is the relation between accelerations of $m_1$ and $m_2$ and how we can find it(is there any other way than writing equations for rope length)?

**UPDATE**

i think I made a mistake at my equations the correct one will be $$L=x_1-x_0+(x_1-x_0+x_0-x_2)+x_2-x_0+x_3-x_2=2x_1+x_3-3x_0$$

$$constant=L+2x_0=2x_1+x_3-x_2$$

So i think the equation for the accelerations will be $2a_2+a_1-a_{P_1}=0$

$P_1$ is the pulley with the smallest circle in picture.If this is true, it means that we **can't** neglect the mass of this pulley. why this happens (a reason explaining with physics)? and how we should proceed to solve this because we just have one relation between accelerations?

**2nd-UPDATE**

taking the upward direction as $y+$, this will be our equations for forces:

$m_1$:$\sum f_y=T-m_1g=m_1a_1$

$P_{smallest}$:$\sum f_y=T-2T-m_{P_{smallest}}g=m_{P_{smallest}}a_{P_{smallest}}$

$P_{medium}$:$\sum f_y=2T-T'-m_{P_{medium}}g=m_{P_{medium}}a_{P_{medium}}$

$m_1$:$\sum f_y=T'-m_2g=m_2a_2$

$P_{largest}$:$\sum f_y=T''-2T-m_{P_{largest}}g=m_{P_{largest}}a_{P_{largest}}$

we can neglect $P_{largest}$ and $P_{medium}$ masses.So we have $$T''=2T$$
$$T'=2T$$

so we going to have four equations: $$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
-T-m_{P_s}g=m_{P_s}a_{P_s} \\ 
2T-m_2g=m_2a_2\\
T-m_1g=m_1a_1\\
2a_2+a_1-a_{P_s}=0
\end{array}
\right.$$

Now what we should do to find $a_2$,$a_1$ and $a_{P_s}$?

Comment: You should be able to solve this system of equations you end up with. Perhaps use linear algebra?

Comment: @Danu,whatever i try to do with equations, i can't find $a_1$ or $a_2$.for example i tried to find $a_1$ and got this $a_1=\frac{m_1g+m_{P_s}g+2m_{P_s}a_2}{-(m_{P_s}+m_1)}$

Answer (score 1):

I see your update but I don't understand the equality, more exactly the right hand side. I get there

$2(x_1 −x_0) +(x_3 −x_2 )$.

This equality is also directly obvious. From it one gets indeed your relation between accelerations

$2a_2 +a_1 −a_{P_{smallest}} =0$

Comment: thanks for your answer. right now i want to know that how we should find the values of the accelerations. more exactly ,should we have value of $M_{P_smallest}$? also does there any other relation between accelerations?

Comment: I have to think. I believe that the masses are needed, both of the smallest and medium pulley and $m_1$ and $m_2$. It's obvious to me that for certain masses all the system will be in equilibrium and the accelerations will vanish.

Comment: Let's label the medium pulley as $P_2$, and the smallest pulley as you named it $P_1$. On each one of these pulleys act three forces, through the ropes of the left and right of each pulley and one force due to gravity.

Comment: I updated the post about this. please take a look at it.

Comment: Label the medium pulley $P_2$. We need its mass too. The masses have weights and they matter no less than the weights of $m_1$ and $m_2$. I also need to know what are the $T$ and $T'$ in your equations. Note that there are two tension forces that act on $P_1$ (besides the gravity force).

Comment: I suggest to label the tension forces that act on the pulleys by $T_{1,center}$, and $T_{1,R}$, and $T_{2,L}$ and $T_{2,R}$. Can we? And I see that $T_{1,R} = -T_{2,L}$.

Comment: I get other equations. $T_{2,L} + T_{2,R} - m_2 g = m_2 a_2$, and $T_{1, central} - m_1 g - T_{2,L} = m_1 a_1$.

Comment: i think your last equation is wrong just two forces are acting on $m_1$,and the reason i neglected mass of medium and large pulley because i want to make things simpler to solve. it can't be done for the small one because the will be $T=0$. also the tension is same in every place in the rope so we have just $T$. thanks for your help and suggestions